# how to display data in which format using dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm making a graph using the Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js, which is based on d3 and crossfilter. i am new in dc.js library.i am trying to display the graph using django framework for python.i am using dataforamat csv. csv is in following format. i am confusing display the data is  display in piechart,rowchart,barchart,bubble chart format.

```
Name,Date,Word,Word_count
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Panag,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,rule:,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Story,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,U.P.,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,leaders,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Mumbai,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Union,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Dimple,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Drivers,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Tennis,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,son,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Style,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Anantnag,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Golf,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Chess,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,cook,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,u.p.,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,best-seller,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Arts,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Interview,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Jaha,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Mehboob,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Other,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Hollywood,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Week,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Modis,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Life,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,TV,1
The Telegram,2014-04-02,Delhi,2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the question, but you don't need django on dc.js, beside to generate the csv you mention. the rest is purely in the browser.

You will need to pre-process the data to convert the string date into a javascript date if you want to filter it (eg. use it as the X axis on a linechart)

As for the various charts provided by dc, you can check that documentation: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md